# docker compose variable substitution

Tags: docker, docker-compose

It seems that I am not understanding something about variable substitution in the following page (my variable `NUM` is not registering): https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#Interpolation

See screenshot below. Running this on mac OSX.

[image: docker-compose up]

Comment: What versions of Docker and Docker Compose?

Answer (score 5):

Regarding [`docker-compose` variable substitution](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/ea8cc1c3dc47c9ed3bff56c5a8d99175b57af650/docs/compose-file.md#variable-substitution), it can depend on how `NUM` has been set.
`set NUM=5` would only set it in the current shell, not for another process.
Make sure to type:

```
export NUM=5
```

Comment: The question is referring compose's variable substitution mechanism, which uses variables from the host, not the container.

Comment: @AdrianMouat Oh... you mean https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/ea8cc1c3dc47c9ed3bff56c5a8d99175b57af650/docs/compose-file.md#variable-substitution

Comment: @AdrianMouat I have rewritten the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

It is mentioned in the [docs](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/tree/270d317/_includes/content/compose-var-sub.md):

> You can use a $$ (double-dollar sign) when your configuration needs a
>   literal dollar sign. This also prevents Compose from interpolating a
>   value, so a $$ allows you to refer to environment variables that you
>   don’t want processed by Compose.
>
> ```
> web:
>   build: .
>   command: "$$VAR_NOT_INTERPOLATED_BY_COMPOSE"
> ```
>
> If you forget and use a single dollar sign ($), Compose interprets the
>   value as an environment variable and will warn you:
>
> The VAR_NOT_INTERPOLATED_BY_COMPOSE is not set. Substituting an empty
>   string.

According to that, line 03 of your compose file should be:

```
command: echo $$NUM
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to $$ solution provided by @ayman-nedjmeddine above you also need to do following, to make shell variables available in compose you have two options

Option 1

- log in as root , set your variable and execute docker-compose
- root>export NUM=5
- root>docker-compose up

Option 2

- use `sudo -E` from user shell, `-E` will propagate user shell env to sudo,
- provide sudo access to docker/docker-compose
- add `:SETENV:` to the command in sudoer file to use `-E` option in sudo
- eg:

  ```
  sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/docker-compose
      ALL   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:SETENV: /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
  sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/docker
      ALL   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:SETENV: /usr/bin/docker
  ```
- finally use

  ```
  user1>export NUM=5
  user1>sudo -E docker-compose up
  ```